# Burp doesn't intercept localhost

Tags: burp

I'm new to burp and is playing around to intercept traffic from my localhost machine (website that I created for testing). However I noticed that burp intercept the css rather that traffic/url. What do I do to make burp intercept my localhost/php request?

My firefox/burp are all configured to 127.0.0.1:8080 as per localhost setting.

[image]

Comment: In Firefox proxy settings there is a little sentence stating `Connections to localhost, 127.0.0.1/8 and ::1 are never passed through a proxy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Burp go to `Proxy -> Options -> Proxy listeners`, and confirm the Running box is ticked.

1. In proxy tab make sure **intercept** is **turned off**.
2. Make sure the proxy in **burp listener** is `127.0.0.1:6666`.
3. Configure your browser to use `127.0.0.1:6666` as its proxy.
4. Configure Burp to use your original LAN proxy (from your original browser configs) as its upstream proxy.
5. Run your browser and access your application.

`Additional reasons could be browser restricted ports.`
You mentioned you are using Firefox so Try this:

1. Type the following into Firefox address bar `about:config`
2. Type the following settings `network.security.ports.banned.override`
3. Enter your port number **6666**